# Guardar información en base de datos MongoDB desde formulario?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, servidor

Quiero guardar la información capturada desde un formulario html en una base de datos MongoDB,tengo el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Intro to Node and MongoDB</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <h1>Into to Node and MongoDB</h1>
 <form method="post" action="/addname">
 <label>Enter Your Name</label><br>
 <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name..." required>
 <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name..." required>
 <input type="submit" value="Add Name">
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Y el siguiente código javascript que sería mi app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


var mongoose = require("mongoose");
/*
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo");
*/

var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo', {
  useMongoClient: true,
  /* other options */
});


var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 firstName: String,
 lastName: String
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});



app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
 var myData = new User(req.body);
 myData.save()
 .then(item => {
 res.send("item saved to database");
 })
 .catch(err => {
 res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
 });
});



app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

Al parecer la petición post está funcionando, al rellenar los campos y presionar el input de tipo submit, sin embargo al revisar la base de datos esta se encuentra vacía, igual que al momento de crearla. ¿Alguien sabe por qué no me guarda la información?

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la respuesta. La cuestión es que estaba utilizando `app.use` para enviar el archivo `index.html`, y en su lugar debí haber usado `app.get` para que escuchara las solicitudes de `/`, así que de esta forma resultó el código 100% funcional:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


var mongoose = require("mongoose");
/*
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo");
*/

var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo', {
  useMongoClient: true,
  /* other options */
});


var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 firstName: String,
 lastName: String
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});



app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
 var myData = new User(req.body);
 myData.save()
 .then(item => {
 res.send("item saved to database");
 })
 .catch(err => {
 res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
 });
});



app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```